# Making a Regex object that matches a Javascript string. Explain method

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is an regular expression from "Javascript:The Good Parts" book

```
//Make a regular expression object that matches a javascript string.
var my_regexp = new RegExp("\"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\\\"])*\"", 'g');
```

What this `[^\\\\\\\"]` expression is matching here?

Comment: What is the question? Do we have to solve it now? :/

Comment: @ItiTyagi  given exp is an regex that matches a javascript string. Just want to know what this [^\\\\\\\"] means in given expression

Comment: actually there are extra backslashes in it for special chars the [^\\\\\\\"] is in real means not a `\  or "`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, strings are surrounded by `"` (or `'`, which this regex doesn't support) and `\` is used to escape characters that would otherwise have a different meaning.

Now, `[^\\\\\\\"]` is a character class for characters that aren't `\` or `"`. However because we're using a string literal to define the regular expression the `"` needs escaping, and because `\` has a special meaning within both strings and regular expressions we need to escape them too.

```
\"        starting characters
\\"       escape `\` for regex
\\\"      escape `"` for regex
\\\\\\"   escape `\` for string
\\\\\\\"  escape `"` for string
```

It's simpler if you use `'` for the string, or a regex literal. The following are all the same.

```
new RegExp("\"(?:\\.|[^\\\\\\\"])*\"", "g");
new RegExp('"(?:\\.|[^\\\\\\"])*"', 'g');
/"(?:\.|[^\\\"])*"/g
```

In fact, `"` doesn't have a special meaning in a regular expression, so escaping it was not necessary.

```
/"(?:\.|[^\\"])*"/g
```

Also note that `.` isn't either `\` or `"`, so the `|` construct is pointless. I would guess this is an error, and that it's intended to be `\\.` - i.e. a `\` followed by any character. That would require four `\` in the original, not two. Without this correction, the expression won't match strings like `"ab\\c"`.

If we want to support `'` as well then things are going to get very complicated, and we probably should just use a simple char-by-char parser, rather than a regular expression.

[RegExp Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Unwrapping `var my_regexp = new RegExp("\"(?:\\.|[^\\\\\\\"])*\"",'g');`:

```
1: new RegExp("\"(?:\\.|[^\\\\\\\"])*\"",'g');
2: /"(?:\.|[^\\\"])*"/g
               ^--- this backslash is not really needed, but does not hurt
```

Matches `"`, followed by any number of `.` or not `\` and not `"`, followed by `"`. Also, since the group has `(?:...)` - it will not actually capture anything, it will just check that such pattern exists.

For example, in a string `I "li.ke" donuts. I "h\ate" potatoes.` it will match `"li.ke"`, but will not match `"h\ate"` because of `\`.

Comment: note the the poster copypasted the expression incorrectly, should be `\\\\.`.

Comment: @RobinsGupta: in my copy of the book there are four slashes for the string version. Two slashes don't make sense.

Comment: @thg435 thanks for the edit. Actually I was having old version of the book.